# Is it possible to bcc someone on every email sent from a list in owa

Tags: email, outlook-web-access, bcc

What I want to do is this:

-Send an email to a list of recipients
-Have one email address bcc'd on every email sent

So that this happens: the email is sent to the whole list of recipients and the bcc email gets a copy of every email sent, rather than just one copy.

I'm using OWA.

Comment: This isn't possible without a desktop email client which supports add-ons

Comment: Oh. Could I write a little script that might do that?

Comment: Yes, you can write a little script. Why not give it a go?

Comment: @Ramhound, is it not? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324021/how-to-create-a-catchall-mailbox-sink-for-exchange-server I guess if this account is OWA-Only or Exchange... I guess it depends on the set up and access...

Comment: @Dave - I already know about that but how does the email sink get added to every email in OWA?  Furthermore how does one run the VBA script within a browser (because the user is using OWA).  *Which is the reason I said it wasn't possible unless they were using a desktop client.*

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. My post was never a difference of opinion, just more of an additional question as to why it isn't supported with this. Thank you